# Undetermined permissions on iOS physical device using Expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am testing on an external iPhone since I know push notifs do not work on the simulator. My Expo tokens weren't being sent to my Firebase database so I dug into the code and discovered that my `status` variable from async call `Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS)` returns as `undetermined`. All the responses I've seen on this forum relate to this issue being from a simulator so I'm confused as to why this is happening.

- The first time I opened the app on iPhone I allowed push notifications.

Here is the corresponding code I am using essentially straight from docs:

`import { Font, AppLoading, Permissions, Notifications } from 'expo';`

and the function called on `componentDidMount()`

> ```
>     registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async (user) => {
>     const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
>         Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
>       );
>       let finalStatus = existingStatus;
>
>       // only ask if permissions have not already been determined, because
>       // iOS won't necessarily prompt the user a second time.
>       if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
>         // Android remote notification permissions are granted during the app
>         // install, so this will only ask on iOS
>
>         const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
>         console.log(status);
>         finalStatus = status;
>       }
>
>       // Stop here if the user did not grant permissions
>       if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
>
>         return;
>       }
>
>       // Get the token that uniquely identifies this device
>       let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
>       alert(token);
>       var updates = {}
>       updates['/expoToken'] = token;
>       database.ref('users').child(user.uid).update(updates)
> }
> ```

This is the status console log after `Permissions.getAsync`

[image]

As you can see, I've been console logging the status variable and it shows undetermined at that point.

How else can I help debug this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Try checking [this](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1695) issue too, might be related.

Comment: @PritishVaidya i guess my overarching question is do I need to be enrolled in apple's developer program for push notifications? This is my first app so I am not, yet. Maybe this is my problem?

Comment: Yes, that is required. Notifications are only sent once you have the certificates configured for your app, and received on the registered devices